# Cant show total amount of purchase in my django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i building a basic ecom site , when i try to make total amount of purchase nothings shows in page,
But i can make total of individual items , But can't figure out how to show total amount of the purchases

**html**

```
<h1>Bill Of Purchase</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 
    <tbody>
    
    {% for obj in item %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
      <td>{{obj.item}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.quantity}}</td>
      <td>${{obj.get_total_item_price}}</td>
    </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>       
    <td>total</td>
    <td>${{item.get_total}}</td>
    
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**views.py**

```
      def bill_page(request):
            
            item= BillItem.objects.all() 
            
            return render(request,'bill.html',{'item':item})
```

**model.py**

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
    ('U', 'Pulses'),
    ('O', 'Oil'),
    ('F', 'Flour'),
    ('V', 'Vegetable')]

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantityofproduct = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quantityAvailable = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,max_length=1)
    CreatedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    UpdatedDate= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class BillItem(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity*self.price

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total_item_price for item in orderitems])
        return total
```

i cant make total amount of purchase , can any one help me.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it 'that' way. There can be better ways but I think doing another query is easiest.
In your `views.py` do

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models import F, FloatField

# in your view method
total=BillItem.objects.aggregate(
            p=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity')),
            output_field=FloatField()
         )
return render(request,'bill.html',{'item':item, 'total':total['p']})
```

and in your template

```
<td>${{total}}</td>
```

Comment: It ignores quantity and gives total amount of all items selected,

Comment: @ashil sry, my bad. I have updated the answer. can you please check if it works?

Comment: Still not getting it ..!

Comment: @ashil what are you getting exactly? and whats your django version?

Comment: Version 2.2, it gives FieldError at/bill ,Expression contain mixed types.You must set output_field

Comment: @ashil, sorry it was my fault. I didn't notice you have two different field types. I have yet again updated the answer. please try if that works.